# How to remove the content before '>' and after space in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, parsing

Here is the example:

`<aNodeName thsisjijdsnjdnjsd>`, and I would like to remove `thsisjijdsnjdnjsd`,

How can I detect the string which is before the `>` and after the space , and trim out it in objective C? Also, please remind that I don't know the `aNodeName` or `thsisjijdsnjdnjsd`, because the data may turn out something like this:

`<anotherNodeName zxzxxzxzxz>`, and I need to remove `zxzxxzxzxz`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags - trust me on this

Comment: @KateGregory — we dont know, if this is meant for html parsing. But note, that I added the link you provided as warning in my answer, in case it is meant for html-parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options

- [Regular expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

  ```
  NSString *string = @"<aNodee thsisjijdsnjdnjsd>";
  NSError *error;
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<(\\S+)( .*)>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                           error:&error];
  NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
  [matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      NSString* nodeName = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];
      NSString* value = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
      NSLog(@"%@ %@",nodeName, value);
  }];
  ```

  [Note, that you shouldn't parse complex html with Regular Expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)
- [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

  ```
  NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
  BOOL recordingValue = NO;

  NSMutableString *valueString = [@"" mutableCopy];
  [scanner setScanLocation:0];
  while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {

      NSString *charAtlocation = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 1)];
      if ([charAtlocation isEqualToString:@" "]){
          recordingValue = YES;
          [valueString appendString:@" "];
      } else{
          if ([charAtlocation isEqualToString:@">"]){
              recordingValue = NO;
          } else if (recordingValue) {
              [valueString appendString:charAtlocation];
          }
      }
      [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
  } ;


  NSLog(@"Scanner approach: %@", valueString);
  NSLog(@"Scanner approach: %@", [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:valueString withString:@""]);
  ```

---

Complete command line based example

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *string = @"<aNodee thsisjijdsnjdnjsd> ";
        NSError *error;
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<([a-zA-z]+)( .*)>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                 error:&error];
        NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
        [matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSString* nodeName = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];
            NSString* value = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
            NSLog(@"Regex approach: %@ %@",nodeName, value);

            NSLog(@"Regex approach: %@", [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:value withString:@""]);
        }];




        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
        BOOL recordingValue = NO;

        NSMutableString *valueString = [@"" mutableCopy];
        [scanner setScanLocation:0];
        while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {

            NSString *charAtlocation = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 1)];
            if ([charAtlocation isEqualToString:@" "]){
                recordingValue = YES;
                [valueString appendString:@" "];
            } else{
                if ([charAtlocation isEqualToString:@">"]){
                    recordingValue = NO;
                } else if (recordingValue) {
                    [valueString appendString:charAtlocation];
                }
            }
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
        } ;


        NSLog(@"Scanner approach: %@", valueString);
        NSLog(@"Scanner approach: %@", [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:valueString withString:@""]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Regex approach: aNodee  thsisjijdsnjdnjsd
Regex approach: <aNodee> 
Scanner approach:  thsisjijdsnjdnjsd
Scanner approach: <aNodee>
```

Comment: Updated the question, I don't have the knowledge that I know the `aNodeName`

Comment: my regex will give you the node name and the other string

Comment: added a nsscanner based example